# NameNode and Datanode not starting in Hadoop on start-dfs.cmd

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

So I am trying to setup Hadoop by using this as reference: [Towardsdatascience.com click here](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-hadoop-3-2-1-single-node-cluster-on-windows-10-ac258dd48aef)

now the error:

```
E:\RIYA\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1\sbin>start-dfs.cmd
```

2 cmd pop up, one for datanode and one for namenode

DataNode Error:

```
************************************************************/
2022-03-11 23:44:42,810 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2022-03-11 23:44:48,486 INFO checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/E:/hadoop-env/hadoop-3.2.1/data/dfs/datanode
2022-03-11 23:44:48,687 WARN checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/E:/hadoop-env/hadoop-3.2.1/data/dfs/datanode
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-03-11 23:44:48,691 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2799)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2900)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2924)
2022-03-11 23:44:48,701 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
2022-03-11 23:44:48,707 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at LAPTOP-7DCG00HD/192.168.56.1
************************************************************/
```

NameNode Error:

```
2022-03-11 23:44:53,048 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:690)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:642)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:953)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:926)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1759)
2022-03-11 23:44:53,064 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
2022-03-11 23:44:53,090 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at LAPTOP-7DCG00HD/192.168.56.1
************************************************************/
```

Files inside my directory: `E:\RIYA\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1\etc\hadoop`

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
<description>MapReduce framework name</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
<description>Yarn Node Manager Aux Service</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>/E:/hadoop-env/hadoop-3.2.1/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/E:/hadoop-env/hadoop-3.2.1/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I have put my hadoop.dll file and winutils.exe file in windows32 folder and mostly I have done everything that has been given on the internet. I have downloaded jar file from [here](https://github.com/FahaoTang/big-data/blob/master/hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar) and moved it to my folder directory `E:\RIYA\hadoop-env\hadoop-3.2.1\share\hadoop\hdfs` with name `hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.bak`. I don't know what steps are remaining to this.

Comment: Try running Hadoop under WSL2, not directly in windows

Comment: Also, this is the exact same error as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426374/all-nodes-getting-shudown-except-namenode-hadoop-3-3-1-windows